# what does the mean of base-b exactly?

Tags: math, hex, decimal, computer-science

i know how to convert from base b to decimal but Im not understand what is base-b exactly. I know we multiply the base to the numbers if we gonna convert to bas 10 then multiply with then is base-b(base 5)?

Comment: Maybe it's 11? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: @ArtemNovikov no. I mean it's 5 always be the base-b ?

Comment: Without context it's hard to understand your problem. But to me it seems like the term "base-b" just means an arbitrary base, i.e. no specific base (unlike "base 5", which is a specific base).

Comment: A one-handed society would consider a base 5 counting system to be natural and right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure math, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to follow this, we should understand the difference between a number and its representation. Let's start with the (natural) numbers. There are two special numbers: zero and one. Zero is the neutral element of addition (i.e. you can add zero to anything without changing it) and one is the neutral element of multiplication. Every other number can be induced by these two numbers. Start with zero. Then, subsequently add one.

A common representation for numbers is the decimal system. However, this is purely arbitrary and any other system could be used as well. There is nothing intrinsic in the number twelve that would require us to write it as 12. The nice thing is that all arithmetic rules are defined on the numbers themselves, not on their representations. Five plus six will always be eleven. No matter how you represent them. You may have already noticed that I use number words when I talk about the numbers and any other representation if I talk about the representation.

Ok, so we have our numbers. Now we need a way to represent them. Imagine we have three symbols `a`, `b`, and `c`. We could just assign the first three numbers to them

```
a (zero)
b (one)
c (two)
```

But then we are out of symbols. As you know, the positional numeral systems solve this by introducing another position. Then, just continue as before. Assign the next few numbers in order

```
ba (three)
bb (four)
bc (five)
ca (six)
cb (seven)
cc (eight)
```

You might want to continue with a third position:

```
baa (nine)
bab (ten)
bac (eleven)
...
```

The base of this system is three (or `ba`) because we have three symbols. We can observe that the digits in the second position stand for an addition of a multiple of three (`b.` stands for `three + .`, `c.` stands for `two times three + .` ...) Expressed in base `ba`, this is: `b. = b * ba + .`, `c. = c * ba + .`. This continues to all positions and you can generalize that a number formed of digits `dn ... d1 d0` can be expressed by the well-known formula:

```
n = Sum(i) di * base^i
```

The intuition behind this formula is that there will be `base` numbers with one digit, `base^2` numbers with two digits and so on. And the `di * base^i` term skips the first few of them (as many such that the first digit matches, then the second and so on).

We can check this at the example of `bac` which should be eleven:

```
n = b * ba^c + a * ba^a + c * ba^a
  = one * three^two + zero * three^one + two * three^zero
  = nine + zero + two
  = eleven
  = bac
```

Remember that the arithmetic rules apply to the numbers and not to the representations? So since we know the definition of our number (second line in the above formula), we can use any other number representation. For example, the decimal one:

```
 n = one * three^two + zero * three^one + two * three^zero
   = 1 * 3^2 + 0*3^1 + 2*3^0
   = 9 + 0 + 2
   = 11 (decimal)
```

But we could also use another base, e.g. base-8:

```
 n = one * three^two + zero * three^one + two * three^zero
   = 1 * 3^2 + 0*3^1 + 2*3^0
   = 11 + 0 + 2
   = 13 (octal)
```

So basically, these systems arise naturally by assigning digit sequences systematically to subsequent numbers. The conversion is so simple because the positional equation applies to the numbers, not to the representations.

I hope this answer was not too abstract and helped you.